# Checking damage for a mini fridge that is plugged in without waiting

Tags: refrigerator

I got a new mini fridge yesterday. As it is my first fridge ever, I had no idea about the oil settling time waiting so I just plugged it in immediately. It is most probably transported in the correct upright position but I can’t be 100% sure.

Now I wonder is there a way that I could check if I somehow damaged it? It seems like working and cooling is okay. Makes a bit weird noises while running but it might be normal I guess.

And would it make sense to plug it off now and wait? Would it help with the oil settling or is it too late now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to know, those weird noises might be noises of imminent failure in the next 1 day, 1 week, 1 month or year... who can tell...

I seriously doubt if there is anything to be gained in turning it off now - any damage is there. However, you might be lucky and it may run for years and it is just normal noise.

Comment: I agree it could have been upside down in storage, the good news you should have a warranty, contact them or take it back, it could be normal , maybe, +

Comment: The company that sold it having it stored upside down and then sold to a customer is exactly what a warranty is for. The op said they were not sure but it failed to work and s new sounds simple enough to me

Comment: @EdBeal who says it was stored upside down? even if it was, the instructions on **every** fridge I have bought new and, I suspect, those that you have bought say to wait 12 hours or more before plugging in to avoid that type of damage...

Comment: If you read my comment I agreed with you and said it could have been upside down at the store, but since you now disagree I guess the + I gave is not warranted